# Spark Scroller in AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark, halo

AdvancedDataGrid uses a Halo Scroller by default. How can I change it to a Spark Scroller?

Answer (score 1):

Have not tried this, but my approach would be to wrap your ADG in a spark Scroller component and change the scrollbar policies in your ADG to "none".  Hope that helps.